# 3D Object Translation in Viewport of WPF

Tags: wpf

I have translate the object by applying the transform on 3DObject. It translate the objects correctly buy rotation of that object is getting disturb means in opposite direction. I want to rotate the 3DObject on its center not on viewport3d center.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us the things you have tried to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you apply the translation and rotation in the correct order.

1. Move the Object so that its center is at the origin (0,0,0)
2. Rotate the Object
3. Translate the Object anywhere you want

If you do this using matrices, multiply the matrices in reverse order!